# Rxjs - check if Observable is empty, without subscribing to it

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I wonder is it possible to check if observable received any value. And I want this without subscribing to it, because I am too lazy to overwrite my current code. Problem is that I create observable in parent component and then passing it to child components. And I need only one tiny thing from it, so subscribing just for that, seems unnecessary...

**parent-component:**

```js
adverts$: Observable<advert[]>;
    
ngOnInit() {
    this.adverts$ = this.advertService.advertsPerUser();
```

**service:**

```js
advertsPerUser() {
    return this.advertsKeysPerUser()
        .map(adKeys => adKeys.map(adKey => this.afDb.object('adverts/' + adKey.$key )))
        .flatMap(val => Observable.combineLatest(val) );
}
```

So my goal is in parent-component.html do something like:

```js
<div *ngIf="adverts$">
```

Comment: An `Observable` doesn't "have" a value, it emits a value when the source emits a value. I don't get what the problem is you have with `subscribe()`? Is it that the value is async? Don't use `Observable` if you don't want async. If you're forced into async, then you're out of luck. There is no way back from async to sync.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer - My only concern here is performance. I  thought if I could check if observable is empty or not, without subscribing to it, it would save some memory... And also it looks weird in general - creating a stream just to check there is anything in it..

Comment: Sounds like a special case of pre-pre-mature optimization ;-)

Comment: You can use `skipWhile` or `skipUntil` operator. but this should be applied at the time of subscription

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short, no.

By default Observable is unicast behaves similar to function, so emits value to observer once it is actually subscribed. It is important it is **similar to function**, subscribing is actual attempt to start those observables. If you think of typical function returns a value (or not), you won't be able to know until function is actually executes and returns its results. Same applies for Observable as well you can't have source's values until you subscribe it.

Answer (score 9):

You can try using defaultIfEmpty operator (see [description](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/defaultifempty)). Supposed your advertsPerUser return a number you could do this:

```js
this.adverts$ = this.advertService.advertsPerUser().map(count => count > 0).defaultIfEmpty(false);
```

in html:

```html
<div *ngIf="adverts$ | async">
```

or with rxjs version 6:

```js
this.adverts$ = this.advertService.advertsPerUser().pipe(
    map(count => count > 0),
    defaultIfEmpty(false)
);
```

Comment: Tip: `defaultIfEmpty` only works if the observable completes without any emissions. It doesn't mean 'default if null or undefined.' So be cautious of that or it will be super confusing!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue where i wanted to check if my response, which is an array of a custom type, was empty or not. Here is my solution

```js
<div *ngIf="(response$ | async).length == 0">
    <p>no results</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the @Deitsch I just made one change to avoid typescript errors:

```js
<div *ngIf="(response$ | async)?.length == 0">
    <p>no results</p>
</div>
```

I added the sign: `?` before `lenght` property

Comment: This was helpful, although in my case I needed this: ```*ngIf="!(response$ | async) == 0">```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defaultIfEmpty` operator to define some default value in case if the source observable is empty.